# RxJava Flowable.Interval backpressure when flatmap with single

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I'm having a scenario where I need to periodically call an API to check for a result. I'm using `Flowable.interval` to create an interval function which calls the API.

However, I'm having trouble with backpressure. In my example below, a new single is created on each tick in the interval. The desired effect is to only call the API if a call is not already in progress

```
Flowable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap {
        System.out.println("Delay $it")

        //simulates API call
        Single.just(1L).doAfterSuccess {
            System.out.println("NEW SINGLE!!!")
        }.delay(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS).doAfterSuccess {
            System.out.println("SINGLE SUCCESS!!!")
        }.toFlowable()
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).blockingFirst()
```

I can solve this using a filter variable like so:

```
var filter = true

Flowable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).filter {
    filter
}.flatMap {

    System.out.println("Delay $it")

    Single.just(1L).doOnSubscribe {
        filter = true
    }.doAfterSuccess {
        System.out.println("NEW SINGLE!!!")
    }.delay(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS).doAfterSuccess {
        System.out.println("SINGLE!!!")
        filter = true
    }.toFlowable()
}.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).blockingFirst()
```

But it seems like a hacky solution. I've tired applying `onBackPressureDrop` after the `interval` function, but it has no effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, I thought `onBackPressureXXX` should handle this, since it's also described in the docs: `The operator generates values based on time and ignores downstream backpressure which
     *  may lead to {@code MissingBackpressureException} at some point in the chain.
     *  Consumers should consider applying one of the {@code onBackpressureXXX} operators as well.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to constrain `flatMap` as well:

```
Flowable.interval(1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.onBackpressureDrop()
.flatMapSingle({
    System.out.println("Delay $it")

    //simulates API call
    Single.just(1L).doAfterSuccess {
        System.out.println("NEW SINGLE!!!")
    }.delay(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS).doAfterSuccess {
        System.out.println("SINGLE SUCCESS!!!")
    }
}, false, 1)  // <----------------------------------------------------------
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.subscribe()
```